# How to send and receive audio from a bluetooth device in OSX 10.9?

Tags: cocoa, audio, bluetooth, osx-mavericks

So I am trying to build this app that would allow you to send and receive some audio trough a bluetooth connection.

I've managed to connect to the device and all but now I have no idea how to play the audio that it's sending or how to send audio to it.

I see in the docs that `IOBluetoothAddSCOAudioDevice` is what you used to install the connected device as an audio device.

But in `OSX 10.9` this method was deprecated with no new one to replace it (at least not specified in the docs).

Does anyone know how am I suppose to get the audio that I receive from the bluetooth device to play on my PC's speakers and the audio that gets recorder with my PC's microphone sent to the bluetooth device?